# "Eilenberg-MacLane property" for the classifying space of a groupoid

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, groupoids

Given a groupoid $G$, its classifying space is defined as the standard geometric realisation of the nerve.

My question is: since the classifying space of a group is the only space up to homotopy that has certain homotopy groups, can something like that be said about the case of a groupoid? For example, do the homotopy groups of $BG$ have some relationship (obviously much less trivial) with the groupoid $G$?

And if not (as I suspect) is there some other "geometrical" invariant of the space $BG$ that yields back $G$ in some form (like the first homotopy group in the case when $G$ is a group)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $G$ is a discrete groupoid, you can take the fundamental groupoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, do the homotopy groups of $BG$ have some relationship (obviously much less trivial) with the groupoid $G$?

Actually, it is not much less trivial at all!  A groupoid is uniquely determined, up to equivalence, by the groups corresponding to its connected components.  Indeed, if $G$ is a groupoid and $G_0\subseteq G$ is a skeleton of $G$, then $G_0$ is a disjoint union of groups (considered as 1-object categories).  Since the inclusion functor of a skeleton of a category is an equivalence of categories, this determines $G$ up to equivalence.

Now, the classifying space functor turns equivalences of categories into homotopy equivalences and disjoint unions of categories into disjoint unions of spaces.  So, if $G$ is a groupoid, then $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to a disjoint union of classifying spaces of groups, namely the groups corresponding to a skeleton of $G$.

Or, to state things more canonically (without choosing a skeleton), the groupoid $G$ is naturally equivalent to the fundamental groupoid  of $BG$, and $BG$ has no higher homotopy groups with respect to any basepoint.  Explicitly, each object of $G$ determines a point of $BG$ and each morphism of $G$ determines a path in $BG$, and this defines a functor $G\to \pi_{\leq 1}(BG)$ which is an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Thanks! Any references? (Other that the one mentioned in the other answer?)

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I would posit that all of this is "obvious" once you've digested the idea that a groupoid is (up to equivalence) just a disjoint union of groups.

Comment: By groupoid do you mean "discrete groupoid"? Or is topology playing a role I don't see? Because by connected components I think we mean "objects connected by arrows".

Comment: Yes, everything I am talking about here is discrete.  (I assumed you were interested only in discrete group(oid)s based on what you wrote in the question.  For instance, for topological groups $G$, it is not true that $BG$ is uniquely determined up to homotopy by its homotopy groups.)

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to consider the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,S)$ of a space $X$ for a set of base points $S$. Similarly we consider a groupoid $G$ as given with its object set say $S$. Its classifying space $BG$ should thus be considered as having a set of base points $S$. Then $\pi_1(BG,S)\cong G$.

For more on this idea see the paper [Modelling and computing homotopy types: I](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357717300460). Note that the homotopy groups $\pi_i(BG,x)$ at any base point $x$ are zero for $i >1$.